# How to develop a logistic regression model using SGL package?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, r-package, lasso-regression

I am currently working with a dataset that has a very large number of variables. Therefore, I decided to use the sparse group LASSO variable selection technique, implemented on the SGL package.

My problem is a logistic regression problem, which is one of the possible models to build using this package. However, when I try to use it, I get an error message. My data frame is called N, and my binary vector is called y:

```
> x <- as.matrix(N)
> y <- as.matrix(Y)
> data <- list(x, y=y)
> sgl_small <- cvSGL(data, groups, type="logit")

Error: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

In the situation before, Y was a binary numeric vector of zeros and ones, so I thought that the problem would be that Y was not a factor, so I tried another time:

```
> x <- as.matrix(N)
> y <- as.factor(Y))
> data <- list(x, y=y)
> sgl_small <- cvSGL(data, groups, type="logit")

Error in seq.default(log(max.lam), 
  log(min.lam), (log(min.lam) -   log(max.lam))/(nlam -  : 
'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
 2: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
 3: In Ops.factor(y, m.y) : '-' not meaningful for factors
```

So this error message seems to indicate that y should not be a factor. I don't know what is going wrong, specially because if I run the cvSGL function considering y as a numeric binary vector, but I build a linear model rather than a logit model (although a linear model is not meaingful for me), it actually works and does not give any error.

I am referring to apply this:

```
> y <- as.matrix(Y)
> data <- list(x, y=y)
> sgl_small <- cvSGL(data, groups, type="linear")
```

I would thank any help, if anyone else have tried to use this package to build a logit model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example on the help page of cvSGL

```
set.seed(1)
n = 50; p = 10;
X = matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol = p, nrow = n)
beta = (-2:2)
y = sample(c(0,1),50, replace = T)
data = list(x = X, y = y)
cvFit = cvSGL(data, type = "logit")
```

As you can see, the parameter "index" (you called it groups) wasn't used in this situation. I don't see how you defined the index in your case. I guess the problem is that you need to define the name of your elements list

```
data <- list(x = x, y=y)
```

Comment: The indez parameter is a vector containing information to build groups of variables. In my case, I applied hierarchical clustering by variables, rather than individuals, in order to generate my groups of variables. In any case, I have tried eliminating the groups parameter, and rewritting the list as you sugested, but it still displays the same error message: Error: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Comment: can you tell me more about the data N, Y?

Comment: Of course, I am working with a dataset of patients with breast cancer. I have 100 patients (rows), and the columns are 20000 genes. This means that N[i,j] = a measure of the value of gene j in patient i. Those are all numeric values, always greater or equal to 0. Meanwhile, Y is a vector of 0 and 1. It has a 0 if the patient did not recover from the cancer, and a 1 if he actually recovered from the cancer. The objective I follow is to study which genes influence more on the recovery of the patients

Comment: You're sure you have no NA, NaN on your N and Y df ?

Comment: I finally found the problem. One of the columns of the matrix was enterely made by zeros, and when I realized this, and removed that column everything started to work. Now Im havving another issue. When I run the code from the package, specifically the cvSGL() function on my data set, R stops working. It actually shows up a window from windows saying that it is needed to stop the program. I am not sure why this is happening, but since it happens with this dataset but no with smaller ones, it may be related with the sample size. I will try to run it on a powerfull computer